# Poner color a mis textos utilizando python

Tags: python

Hola necesito que cuando escriba una fila con `writerow` en un fichero me ponga el texto con un formato o con un color. Y mi otra petición sí podría poner color a una determinado elemento de la lista desde python.
Comparto con vosotros el código:

```
import csv


def leer():
    m1 = open("archivo1.csv", "r")
    m1_csv = csv.reader(m1)
    var = ""
    for i, x in enumerate(m1_csv):

        lista0 = x[0:1]
        lista1 = x[1:2]
        header = str1 = ''.join(lista0)
        header1 = header[9:13]
        str1 = ''.join(lista1)
        str1 = str1[1:]
        str2 = str1[0:32]

        listas = []
        listas.append("The next header ")
        listas.append(header1)
        listas.append("")
        if header1 == "goin":
            listas.remove("")
            listas.remove("goin")
            listas.append("error")
            listas.append(" the hash is outdate: " + str2)

        if header1 == "omin":
            listas.remove("")
            listas.remove("omin")
            listas.append("error")
            listas.append(" the hash is outdate: " + str2)

        if str2 == "074e3e3e82db7610dbeafd95c22d20a2":
            listas.remove("")
            listas.append(" is using for speaking")
            listas.append(" example bla bla bla the packet")
            listas.append(" Incident: you can get powers")
        else:
            s = "hola"

        listo = ["OUTGOING HEADERS"]
        listos = ["INCOMING HEADERS"]

        m2_c = csv.writer(open("archivo2.csv", "a"), lineterminator='\n')
        if i == 0:
            m2_c.writerow(listo)
        if i == 468:
            m2_c.writerow(listos)
        m2_c.writerow(listas)
    m1.close()
```

Bueno ahí esté el código es eso para no tener yo que darle formato al texto hacerlo desde python.

Comment: Un fichero csv no permite ningún tipo de formateo, solo es un fichero de texto delimitado por comas. Puedes usar otros formatos para hacer lo que quieres hacer pero ya no serán un csv.

Comment: un archivo CSV es un fichero escrito en texto plano por lo que no puede tener elementos como colores u otros formatos, si quieres que tenga esos formatos utiliza un archivo que soporte text enriquecido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los archivos csv son simples archivos de texto con un formato específico, no tienen en cuenta colores para el texto o algún tipo de letra en especial, si buscas eso lo que necesitas en un xls(x). Podrías usar la libreria [`xlsxwritter`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter). Un ejemplo de su web:

```
import xlsxwriter


# Create an new Excel file and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Widen the first column to make the text clearer.
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 20)

# Add a bold format to use to highlight cells.
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

# Write some simple text.
worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello')

# Text with formatting.
worksheet.write('A2', 'World', bold)

# Write some numbers, with row/column notation.
worksheet.write(2, 0, 123)
worksheet.write(3, 0, 123.456)

# Insert an image.
worksheet.insert_image('B5', 'logo.png')

workbook.close()
```

Como ves formatea en texto en este caso dandole `bold` en un workbook.

Comment: esto lo veo posible la verda que me ahorraria el trabajo de darle el formato porq

Comment: me ahorarria el trabajo se me corto la linea xd ya que me da pereza darle formato con excel pero al final uso excel para añadir columnas y darle el formato para que sea mas apreciable a la vista sobretodo porque tengo ficheros con datos y luego python los modifico con listas y luego les voy cambiando la apariencia